# htaccess | redirect all to template less the primary directory

Tags: .htaccess, templates, mod-rewrite

I need to access all addresses are redirected to a directory (or an include) in a template file. For example:

```
/sports/basketball/ ==> /template_sport.php?idsport=$1
/sports/soccer/ ==> /template_sport.php?idsport=$1
/sports/tennis/ ==> /template_sport.php?idsport=$1
```

But instead, if we access /sports/ (no subdirectory) to load the page that is in that directory.

I've done with this ... subdirectories and work well, but when I access / sports / also I try to access / plantilla_deporte.php ....

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} sports/(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) /template_sport.php?idsport=$1
```

how I can add the exception to that if you directly to /sports/ not find the template?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sports/([^/]+)
RewriteRule .* http://example.com/sports/template_sport.php?idsport=%1 [L]
```

It will map silently all URLs like this one:

`http://example.com/sports/basketball`

To:

`http://example.com/sports/template_sport.php?idsport=basketball`

And it will do nothing when the incoming URL is just:

`http://example.com/sports/`

Comment: OK! It's perfect... then I can get the IDSport with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Comment: but if I like to get de idsport with the $_GET['idsport']  ???

I try to put ?idsport=$1 but the parameter is not send... in your example send "xx"

Comment: mmm.. thanks, but, continue not sending nothing.... the result of $_GET['id'] is void  :(

Comment: but don't worry... its valid for me... i can get the IDSport with the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ... it do any str_replace and I get my valid result.... THANKS X 1000 !! :)

Comment: Should not be `idsport` according to your question?

Comment: If it isn't `idsport`just change it in the rule for the key name you are actually using.

Comment: sorry... I would say $_GET['idsport']
as if the parameter is not sent, or was sent empty

Comment: The query in the rewrite rule is `template_sport.php?idsport=whatever`, before the [L] flag. Just replace `idsport` with the name you are actually using. i.e `id`

Comment: Yes, I did not see your last comment. But the best thing to do is to replace it in the rule as described in my last comment.

Comment: I think the problem is that %1 is empty ... . because if I put ?idsport=xxx in the page template returns the value of xxx .... but with idsport=%1 is as if not send anything, it is as if %1 is empty

Comment: `%1` is the value in the incoming URL. For example, in `http://example.com/sports/basketball`, `%1` is `basketball`. It is always the folder name that follows `sports`.

Comment: I think I understand the problem. In your page template put only the URL. `http://example.com/sports/basketball`, for example. The mapped URL `http://example.com/sports/template_sport.php?idsport=%1` can't be there. The rewrite rule will do that silently.

Comment: yes... it's true....
acces directly, the parameter send ok.... with rewrite rule... not send it....

Comment: Please try `$_REQUEST['idsport']` instead of the $_GET and let me know. I am sure the rule works so I want to find out why doesn't work for you.

Comment: but don't worry... i can do all that I need with the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Comment: OK. Sorry I could not help with the problem.

Comment: sorry? why??? you solvented my problem !! thanks for all.. you're a experted user !! thanks again :)